# How do I find the Git file I was working on

Tags: git

I created a new branch.

I thought creating a new branch would switch to it.  I now know I should use this code instead `git checkout -b <branch_name>`

I worked on my file and got it working.

I did a commit and saw this message
**[detached HEAD decdc89] number of loops works**

I still assumed I was on the branch I had created, and it would be a good idea to commit as my code worked.

Then I thought I would merge it

So I `git checkout master`

it said

**Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:**

I did `git merge making-the-number-of-items-work`

But it the work wasn't on that branch, obviously it wouldn't have made many changes.  In fact possibly it merged old changes, I'm not really sure.

How can I find that original bit of code which appears to have been in detached head mode, or have I lost it?  As I made a commit I'm sure there is a way back, but I don't know the commit number.

I tried `git log --all` but I can't see the commit message anywhere

Sorry for such a badly posed question I really don't know the terms for Git all that well yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `git reflog`, look for your commit and copy his sha1. Then checkout the branch you want to work for and cherry-pick that commit : `git cherry-pick the-sha1` : this will applies your commit on that branch, exactly as if you just committed.

Comment: Note in this case that the OP's hash ID is right there in the question: `detached HEAD decdc89`. Using the reflog is the way to find it if you don't already have it on your screen, but in this case it's even easier!

Comment: @torek that's why I posted it, I knew it was useful, but I didn't know how to use it.  So now I can change to my branch and then type `git cherry-pick decdc89` and it will apply the commit right?

Comment: @Eoin you can verify this is your commit with `git show decdc89` and then cherry-pick it, yes !